# Express routing static file: Failed to load module script

Tags: node.js, express, angular9, production, dirname

I'm serving my Angular 9 application the same way I always have, and this is the first time I'm experiencing this issue.

I keep getting the following error: "Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html".

I've scoured the net for answers and can't seem to find anything that fixes it. Everything I have done seems to adhere to the advice given. I'm wondering if this is a new issue with Angular v9?

My express app.js is located in another folder to my Angular project. Below is my folder structure:

- client

  - dist

    - index.html
- middle-tier

  - app.js

app.js:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('*/', (req, res) => { 
    const indexFile = path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/index.html');
    res.sendFile(indexFile);
})
```

The file path is correct, I've consoled logged it and it all adds up. I changed the output path in the angular.json also to just dist instead of having another subfolder.

I am still getting this error.

Comment: You didn't mention what error you get.

Comment: Have you tried `res.sendFile('../client/dist/index.html', {root: __dirname })` ?

Comment: @MorKadosh Oh I'm silly, thanks for that I've updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried something like `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')))`? [More here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: @DhruvShah I am getting "ForbiddenError: Forbidden" when attempting to use that.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you always respond with `index.html` file and if the file contains some `<script>` tags then the browser would expect to receive a `.js` file but your server responds with a `.html` file and that's why you get the error

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I can confirm that this is the working solution. Many thanks for your support, I appreciate it.

Comment: @LewisMorgans glad I could help. Posted as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `express.static()` for that:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')))
```

The issue here is that you always respond with `index.html` file and if the file contains some `<script>` tags then the browser would expect to receive a `.js` file but your server responds with a `.html` file and that's why you get the error.